# Remove unsafe HTTP characters from a string

Tags: perl, escaping, perl-module

I have to send a bunch of string variables as payloads in a HTTP POST message using Perl.

I want to remove "unsafe" characters, such as `< > “ ‘ % ; ) ( & +` from my string variable.

I know I can use a regex pattern to find and replace each of these characters, but I am wondering if there's any existing Perl library that already does that.

For example, I found [`Apache::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache::Util)

```
my $esc = Apache::Util::escape_uri($uri);
```

Can I use `Apache::Util::escape` for this? Or is there a better way?

**EDIT 1:** I have already mentioned that by unsafe, I mean characters like `< > “ ‘ % ; ) ( & +` which can be used in SQL-injection. I don't know how to describe this problem better.

**EDIT 2:** Here's the code that I am working on -it's an Embedded perl code:

```
$cgi = CGI->new();
my $param1 = $cgi->param('param1');
my $param2 = $cgi->param('param2');
my $param3 = $cgi->param('param3');

# I want to remove unsafe characters (< > “ ‘ % ; ) ( & +) from $param1, $param2 and $param3
# Q is, do I use Apache::Util::escape_uri; even if that's for removing unsafe chars from URI?
# OR do I use URI::Escape 'uri_escape';? 
$script = <<__HTML__;
    <script>
       API.call ({
            'paramA': '$param1',
            'paramB': '$param2',
            'paramC': '$param3'
        });
    </script>
__HTML__
```

**EDIT 3:** If anyone else has the same question, I ended up writing a perl function that looks for certain characters such as "(", "{", "$", ";", etc and removes them from your provided string parameter.

List of all characters that I am escaping are: 
`` ";", "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}", "~", "`", "/", "<", ">", "&", "|", "'", "\"", "\\" ``

Obviously, there's room for exclusions as well.

Comment: Do you currently `use CGI`? There's a function similar to `A::U::escape_uri()`. http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#AUTOESCAPING-HTML

Comment: I just noticed: you want to ***send*** your data already escaped, so you're writing the client side? If I'm right, then please tell what modules you already use.

Comment: To elaborate a little more, this is an embedded perl page. I am generating some data as perl string variables, that I will send as a simple JavaScript POST call in that EPL page. So I want clean up my variables before the JavaScript POST call.

Comment: We need to know what is receiving the data to know how to escape or encode it. You're saying it's payload in an HTTP POST request. Depending on the `content-type` of that request your payload can contain whatever you want. There is no need to escape anything per se. Please give more information.

Comment: The server (receiver) expects the data only as base64 encoded. The content-type is set to text/plain.

Comment: ***unsafe*** has many interpretations. What do you want to do?

Comment: Please *edit* your question to put all elaborations into your original post

Comment: What data do you need to escape? If it's not a URI then my answer is worthless

Comment: *"I mean characters like `< > “ ‘ % ; ) ( & +`"* The problem is that we cannot know what characters are *"like"* those for your purpose.

Comment: You should not try to "escape" your way around SQL injection vulnerabilities using a mechanism like this.  You avoid vulnerabilities by writing code that isn't vulnerable -- using prepared statements and placeholders.  Anything short of that is only a partial solution with a false sense of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general definition of *unsafe* characters, so it falls to you to determine whether any of your answers fulfill your requirement

Looking at [*the source of `Apache::Util`*](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GOZER/mod_perl-1.31/Util/Util.pm) it does some very unpleasant things to its own name space, and I wouldn't trust it. It is intended to be used as a component of `mod_perl`, and shouldn't be accessed in isolation

I think the canonical way of escaping HTTP URIs is to use the [`URI::Escape`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape) module

```
use URI::Escape 'uri_escape';
```

You must provide data and code for any more help than this

Comment: I think this is sufficient for my needs. By unsafe, I have already mentioned that I want to remove ``< > “ ‘ % ; ) ( & +`` which can be potentially used for SQL-injection. If ``URI::Escape 'uri_escape'` does that, then that's all I need.